# Belongs_to multiple same models. Why "magic" doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, belongs-to

I have made two models: User and Game. I need each game has to have a host and guest, and they are both just users.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guest, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :host, class_name: 'User'
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hosted_games, :class_name => 'Game', :foreign_key => 'host_id'
  has_many :guested_games, :class_name => 'Game', :foreign_key => 'guest_id'
end
```

and the migration for Game

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.references :host, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :guest, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My question is why in my view

```
game.host.name
```

is not working and I have to use

```
User.find(game.host_id).name
```

instead?

But when I create Tweet and Zombie where Tweet belongs_to :zombie, Zombie has_many :tweets and then magical tweet.zombie.name works?

**EDIT:**
The error message is

```
*uninitialized constant Game::Host*
```

in line: <%= game.host.name %>

```
<% @games.each do |game| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= game.host.name %></td>
    <td><%= User.find(game.guest_id).name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', game %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_game_path(game) %></td>
```

Comment: `game.host.name` is not working....explain ? Error message ?

Comment: I added error message.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I should write it in an answering post, but I managed what was a problem, I think.

I made

```
rake db:reset
```

and no db:migrate after that like previously.

So it looks like my code is good. The problem was my messing with git and database, I think. I am not sure, but I want to spare your time trying to solve my probably solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a typo somewhere... the error suggest you're trying to access `game.Host` instead of `game.host` (beware of using capital letters)

Otherwise, it may be a confilct in method names... did you override the `host` method in your Game class ?

Comment: It is just a new created project with Game and User from scaffold. game.guest.name is not working too ("uninitialized constant Game::Guest"). I didn't type almost nothing manually and have no methods.